# iRedMail problem with amavis, clamav and freshclam

Tags: centos, email-server, clamav, amavis

I have installed iRedMail on Centos and have problem with starting freshclam (after service freshclam start system says that freshclam is already started but service freshclam status says that freshclam is stopped). Freshclam log file is empty.

Maillog says that there is also problem with amavis and clamav:

> amavis[29807]: (29807-06) (!)run_av (ClamAV-clamd) FAILED - unexpected , output="/var/amavis/tmp/amavis-20110512T130639-29807/parts: lstat() failed: Permission denied. ERROR\n"
>
> May 12 13:06:39 poczta amavis[29807]: (29807-06) (!)ClamAV-clamd av-scanner FAILED: CODE(0xa14b3bc) unexpected , output="/var/amavis/tmp/amavis-20110512T130639-29807/parts: lstat() failed: Permission denied. ERROR\n" at (eval 103) line 594.
>
> May 12 13:06:39 poczta amavis[29807]: (29807-06) (!!)WARN: all primary virus scanners failed, considering backups
>
> May 12 13:06:39 poczta amavis[29807]: (29807-06) (!)run_av (ClamAV-clamscan) FAILED - unexpected exit 2, output="WARNING: Ignoring deprecated option --disable-summary\nERROR: Option --tempdir requires a non-empty string argument\nERROR: Can't parse command line options"
>
> May 12 13:06:39 poczta amavis[29807]: (29807-06) (!)ClamAV-clamscan av-scanner FAILED: /usr/bin/clamscan unexpected exit 2, output="WARNING: Ignoring deprecated option --disable-summary\nERROR: Option --tempdir requires a non-empty string argument\nERROR: Can't parse command line options" at (eval 103) line 594.
>
> May 12 13:06:39 poczta amavis[29807]: (29807-06) (!!)TROUBLE in check_mail: virus_scan FAILED: AV: ALL VIRUS SCANNERS FAILED
>   May 12 13:06:39 poczta amavis[29807]: (29807-06) (!)PRESERVING EVIDENCE in /var/amavis/tmp/amavis-20110512T130639-29807
>
> May 12 13:06:39 poczta postfix/smtp[31224]: 0895239D0002: to=, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=13075, delays=13075/0.01/0/0.06, dsn=4.5.0, status=deferred (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 451 4.5.0 Error in processing, id=29807-06, virus_scan FAILED: AV: ALL VIRUS SCANNERS FAILED (in reply to end of DATA command))
>
> May 12 13:21:39 poczta postfix/qmgr[7047]: A5B2939D0992: from=, size=523, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>   May 12 13:21:39 poczta amavis[29808]: (29808-06) (!)run_av (ClamAV-clamd) FAILED - unexpected , output="/var/amavis/tmp/amavis-20110512T132139-29808/parts: lstat() failed: Permission denied. ERROR\n"
>
> May 12 13:21:39 poczta amavis[29808]: (29808-06) (!)ClamAV-clamd av-scanner FAILED: CODE(0xa14b3bc) unexpected , output="/var/amavis/tmp/amavis-20110512T132139-29808/parts: lstat() failed: Permission denied. ERROR\n" at (eval 103) line 594.
>
> May 12 13:21:39 poczta amavis[29808]: (29808-06) (!!)WARN: all primary virus scanners failed, considering backups
>
> May 12 13:21:39 poczta amavis[29808]: (29808-06) (!)run_av (ClamAV-clamscan) FAILED - unexpected exit 2, output="WARNING: Ignoring deprecated option --disable-summary\nERROR: Option --tempdir requires a non-empty string argument\nERROR: Can't parse command line options"
>
> May 12 13:21:39 poczta amavis[29808]: (29808-06) (!)ClamAV-clamscan av-scanner FAILED: /usr/bin/clamscan unexpected exit 2, output="WARNING: Ignoring deprecated option --disable-summary\nERROR: Option --tempdir requires a non-empty string argument\nERROR: Can't parse command line options" at (eval 103) line 594.
>
> May 12 13:21:39 poczta amavis[29808]: (29808-06) (!!)TROUBLE in check_mail: virus_scan FAILED: AV: ALL VIRUS SCANNERS FAILED
>
> May 12 13:21:39 poczta amavis[29808]: (29808-06) (!)PRESERVING EVIDENCE in /var/amavis/tmp/amavis-20110512T132139-29808`

mailq output says:

> 523 Thu May 12 09:46:09  fromemail@domain.com
>   (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 451 4.5.0 Error in processing, id=29808-06, virus_scan FAILED: AV: ALL VIRUS SCANNERS FAILED (in reply to end of DATA command))
>                                            someemail@domain.com

I have spent all day trying to resolve this issues. Maybe you can tell me what is the reason of this problems? And how can resolve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with starting script.

`service freshclam start`

dont work but running it manualy works fine

`/usr/bin/freshclam -d -c 2`